# Print file name and line number to log

Tags: specman

I would like to print file name and line number to log file, similar to `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` is SV.

1. Is it possible?
2. Can I print the stack, as `stack()` in SV behaves?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In *e*, there is no "general" syntax to access module name or line number, but there exists a syntax that can be used in `define as` macros.
For example, you can define a macro like this, to print an expression along with the current line and module name:

```
define <my'action> "out_with_line_number <exp>" as {
    out("<current_line_num> @<current_module_name>: ", <exp>);
};
```

Regarding the second question, there exists a predefined global method `print_stack_trace()`.